# How To Access Variable of Parent Class In Child Class

Tags: java

I have problem in java for accessing variable in class
for example
I create two class

```
public class LoginHandler {

     public Void Login() {
          String un = "prob";
     }
}

public class LogoutHandler extends LoginHandler (

     public Void Logout() {
          System..out.print(un);
     }
}
```

I have one class LoginHandler this class contain one method. this method contain one variable like un. I have second class LogoutHandler extedns with LoginHandler and I want to access variable of un in Logout class how can i do this ??

Comment: It's a local variable - it can't be accessed from outside it, regardless of inheritance. Perhaps you meant to have it as a data member?

Comment: Your question has **nothing** to do with Javascript, Java-EE, Swing or Functional Programming -- why the tags? I've removed them for you.

Comment: Also, since you're asking about [tag:java], I assume you meant `void` and not `Void`?

Comment: @Hovercraf Full Of Eels I was about to do the same. good call.

Comment: Also the question has nothing to do with inheritance and all to do with *variable scope*. You'll want to look this up.

Comment: don't look at error i want to find solution :(

Answer (score 1):

You will never be able to access variable `un` in the child class, because variable `un` was defined inside a function and not as a field of that class.

If you convert that variable into a field of the parent class, the child class will be able to access under the following circumstances:

1. The visibility modifier of `un` is not private and the child class is in the same package as the parent class.
2. The visibility modifier is protected or public and the child class is in any package.

Answer (score 0):

if your variable un is a class member and at least protected, yes:

```
public class LoginHandler {
   protected String un;
   public Void Login() {
       un = "prob";
   }
}

public class LogoutHandler extends LoginHandler (

    public Void Logout() {
        System.out.print(un);
    }
 }
```

but you should overthink your design I'd say